# PyMongo - Aggregate doesn't work with group

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to make the following aggregate in my Python Project:

```
pipeline = [
            {
                '$group': {
                    'date': { '$max': "$date" },
                    '_id': {
                        'interface': "$interface",
                        'message': "$message",
                        'server': "$server"
                    },
                    'record_count': {
                        '$sum': '1'
                    } 
                }
            }
        ]
errors = EntryError.objects.aggregate(pipeline)
```

But when the `aggregate` function is executed, it gives me the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Each element of the 'pipeline' array must be an object
```

But the same pipeline code works on Robo3T and when using mongo shell.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.

The code that solved everything it's this one:

```
pipeline = {
    "$group": {
        "date": {"$max": "$date"},
        "_id": {
            "interface": "$interface",
            "message": "$message",
            "server": "$server"
        },
        "record_count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}

errors = EntryError.objects.filter(
    date__gte=start_date, 
    date__lte=end_date
).aggregate(pipeline)
```

"pipeline" as dict instead of list.